# KubernetesPodOperator specify dictionary resources

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-pod

Somehow if I specify resource in my KubernetesPodOperator, the DAG will fail. Looks like the pod is created at least it attempts to create it. The log says `Event: XXXXX-e59a4be6 had an event of type Pending`.

`resource_config = {'limit_memory': 1, 'limit_cpu': 1, 'request_memory': 1, 'request_cpu': 1}`

```
dagA = KubernetesPodOperator(
            name="podA", namespace='my-app', task_id="task1", resources=resource_config,
    ...
```

If I don't specify the resource, it will run. The `resource` param is of type dictionary looking at code.

Did anyone have this issue?

Comment: Look at pod-level errors using the GKE Dashboards to look at the logs for your particular Workload, or use Stackdriver Logging. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dashboards You could also try increasing the `startup_timeout_seconds`

Comment: Also can you post the entire airflow exception?

Comment: I extracted the json manifest generated by airflow. I run the `kubectl apply -f my-pod.json`. This is the error: `9s          Warning   FailedCreatePodSandBox   pod/mypod-aa1                          Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "mypod-aa1": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:301: running exec setns process for init caused \"signal: killed\"": unknown`

Comment: If I remove the `resources` section in the json file, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Specifying a whole integer values does not work based on the examples [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/composer/workflows/kubernetes_pod_operator.py). This resource spec works:

```
resource_config = {'limit_memory': '1024Mi', 'limit_cpu': '500m'}
```

So I think that is the correct way for specifying the values.